# How to search numbers of a list in a nested list and get its indexes in other nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I declared:

```
anyNums = [
    [1,8,4], 
    [3, 4, 5, 6], 
    [20, 47, 47], 
    [4, 5, 1]
]   #List for find the numbers

numsToSearch = [1, 47, 20]    #Numbers to search

rtsian = [0, 2, 3]    #Rows to search in any numbers
```

And what I want to do is for example search if `numsToSearch[0]` is in `anyNums[rtsian[0]]` (In words this would be as, I am looking for the index of number 1 in the 0 row of `anyNums`) and if it is `True` get its index or indices in other nested list named as `indices` and if it is not true just append in the nested list `"The number is not in the list"`, then again search if `numsToSearch[1]` is in `anyNums[rtsian[1]]` and if it is `True`, get its index or indices in the nested list `indices`. If it is `False`, then just append in the nested list `"The number is not in the list"`.

This process is repeated for the other ones. So at the final when I print `indices` this displays in console `[[0], [1,2], ["The number is not in the list"]]`.

I just have tried this:

```
anyNums = [
    [1,8,4], 
    [3, 4, 5, 6], 
    [20, 47, 47], 
    [4, 5, 1]
]   #List for find the numbers

numsToSearch = [1, 47, 20]    #Numbers to search

rtsian = [0, 2, 3]    #Specially rows to search in any numbers

indices = []
    
for i in range(len(rtsian)):
    for j in range(len(anyNums[i])):
        if numsToSearch[i] in anyNums[rtsian[i]]:
            indices[i].append(
                anyNums[rtsian[i]].index(
                    anyNums[rtsian[i]][j]
                )
            )
        else:
            indices[i].append("The number is not in the list")
print(indices)
```

With that I get the next error `IndexError: list index out of range` because I know I am lost with the correct indices for the for loops and lists.

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: if the index bothers you, try for i,v in enumerate(some_list) instead of for i in range(len(...))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were quite some problems in your code. Some of the major ones were

- `indixes[i].append()` : but you just created indixes list and never created indixes[i] sublist. To fix this you can add `indixes.append([])` just as the first line inside your outer `for` loop.
- `for j in range(len(anyNums[i]))` : I think here you want to iterate over the row provided by `rtsian` so a better one would be `for j in range(len(anyNums[rtsian[i]]))`

The above two were producing the `IndexError`.

After resolving the above two still you won't get the desired output, so i did some more changes in the code::

```
anyNums = [[1,8,4], 
           [3, 4, 5, 6], 
           [20, 47, 47], 
           [4, 5, 1]]       #List for find the numbers
numsToSearch = [1, 47, 20]  #Numbers to search

rtsian = [0, 2, 3]          #Specially rows to search in any numbers

indixes = []
    
for i in range(len(rtsian)):
    indixes.append([])
    found = False
    for j in range(len(anyNums[rtsian[i]])):
        if numsToSearch[i] == anyNums[rtsian[i]][j]:
            indixes[i].append(j)
            found = True
    if not found:
        indixes[i].append("The number is not in the list")
print(indixes)
```

Output:

```
[[0], [1, 2], ['The number is not in the list']]
```

Note : the above would be an intuitive code for OP, although it may not be the most optimized code possible to solve his query.